# C# WPF Entity Framework SQLite: select distinct values from table

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I have a SQLite database with a table that contains columns `ID, Item, Price`, (etc)

```
public static List<BudgetModel> GetBudgets()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        return db.Budget.OrderBy(b => b.BudgetID).ToList();
    }
}
```

This code returns a list with all the content of the table.

I want just the values from item and them to be distinct.

But if I do this (or any other variation I found on Stack or the WWW)

```
public static List<BudgetModel> GetBudgetsDistinct()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Budget
                       .Select(o => o.Item)
                       .Distinct().ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get a conversion error:

> Type "System.Collections.Generic.List" can not be converted into implicit "System.Collections.Generic.List<BudgIT.Models.BudgetModel>"
> (*translated from German*)

For me (beginner) it looks like it is not able to convert from list to list...

Sure the difference is `BudgIT.Models.BudgetModel` - but how to fix it?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Additional info: this is how I call this code from my view model:

```
ItemList = new BindableCollection<BudgetModel>(BudgetData.GetBudgetsDistinct());
```

Edit:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BudgIT.Models
{
    public class BudgetModel
    {
        [Key] public int BudgetID { get; set; }
        public int MarketID { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public bool Offer { get; set; }
        public bool Luxury { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Receipt { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your entity data model class (`BudgetModel`?)

Comment: The `Select` call changes the element type of the collection from `BudgetModel` to the type of `BudgetModel.Item`.

Comment: I have edited my Question and add the Class... @Clemens Ok and how do i prevent this? or how do i Change the type back. I think i am to new to c# right now to know what to change :/

Comment: You won't use Select. It is unclear why you did that in the first place. Maybe you wanted to use `DistinctBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function like this

```
public static List<BudgetModel> GetBudgetsDistinct()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var result = db.Budget
                   .DistinctBy(x => x.Item).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

- this will pick first object by your order to the result

ex

| BudgetID | MarketId | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Budget1 | Mk1 | Item1 |
| Budget2 | Mk1 | Item2 |
| Budget3 | Mk2 | Item2 |

and you distinct by Item

you will get only Budget1, Budget2 but you can order its base on your need